# Как сделать адаптивную высоту html?

Tags: html, css, height, adaptive

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста, я самоучка, и плохо знаю html и css. Я пытался сделать что то типо странички с диалогом, как в мобильном приложении вк, у меня получилось сделать все, кроме адаптивной высоты, уж никак не получается...

Можете пожалуйста написать небольшой код, чтобы показать сам принцип работы, как так сделать? (если можете, то на background показать), с width: 650px; Дело в том, что у меня с компьютера работает все супер, прям как надо, но как только захожу на сайт с телефона, то все.. Высота у меня выше половины странички...

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вам поможет использовать единицы измерения vw (1% от ширины окна) и vh (1% от высоты окна). Либо устанавливать размер в % (считается от родительского контейнера). Почитать про это можно, например, [там](https://html5book.ru/edinicy-izmereniya-vh-vw-vmin-vmax/)